# Created a Class to generate a box widget in dart. Problems with passing color

Tags: dart

I'm trying to write a class in dart that would generate a box widget when initialised. I'm trying to pass the color in the constructor and use the same inside the SizedBox widget. But I'm getting an error "The instance member 'color' can't be accessed in an initializer".

```
    class GenerateBox{
      final int id;
      final Color color;
    final bool safe;
    final bool home;
    final String startpoint;
    
      GenerateBox(this.id, this.safe, this.home, this.startpoint, this.color);
    
      Widget Box = SizedBox(
        height:100,
          width:100,
          child: DecoratedBox(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      color: color,
      ),
      )
      );
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the build method:

```
class GenerateBox extends StatelessWidget{
    final int id;
    final Color color;
    final bool safe;
    final bool home;
    final String startpoint;
    
      GenerateBox(this.id, this.safe, this.home, this.startpoint, this.color);

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        height:100,
          width:100,
          child: DecoratedBox(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      color: color,
      ),
      )
      );
}
    
    }
```

Alternatively you can use static  method as below:

```
class GenerateBox{
static SizedBox showSizedBox(
BuildContext context, {
final int id;
    Color color;
    bool safe;
    bool home;
    String startpoint;
    }){
return SizedBox(
        height:100,
          width:100,
          child: DecoratedBox(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      color: color,
      ),
      )
      ); 
}
}
```

you can call above like this:
call it like this:
return GenerateBox.showSizedBox(context,
color: color, safe: safe, home: home, startpoint: startpoint);